# Getting this error while I am cloning a repository fro github in Visual Studio 2022. Error is related to NuGet Package

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the first time that I did clone a repository in Visual Studio.
I have tried to change version of .NET Framework and restore as well still again and again I am getting the same error. I have already restored all packages

Error:

> This project references NuGet Packages that are missing on this computer. Use NutGet Package restore to download them

Answer (score 0):

go to project -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Browse -> search "the missing file"
or
try to follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/consume?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows